# to or for. which one should I use in this sentence

Tags: prepositions

I am confused what should I write?

it is threatening to them.

it is threatening for them.

however, to is appropriate for me because I am indicating them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It is threatening to them," is more familiar to me.  "It is threatening for them," would be unusual, but it would not give me pause.  Either is probably acceptable, but the first is safest.